# how to disable two way binding (security issue)

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, angularjs-ng-disabled

I'm facing an issue here that happens when the final user edit the HTML in the browser and change the pages behavior. Lets say I have an `input` with `disabled="true"` and another attribute that makes the two way binding happen `ng-model="MyModel"`.

Our pages were designed to support insert and edit in the same page (it was built on top of the ASP.NET MVC Framework), so we use the routes provided by it (and I can't change it).
So, deppending on the user role or any other condition, some fields may have the disabled attribute equals to true or false, and here is where the problems appears.

If the user edit the HTML and change the field that was previously disabled, he can now edit and change my model that he should not be able to change.
Sometimes, such fields cannot be handled(validated) in the backend because the backend knows that it may be changed by a user that has permission to do it.

Note: The user with roles to edit those fields is just an example, sometimes is just impossible to identify using validations in the backend when the field can or cannot be edited, in that case, we apply some view logic to decide when setting a field as disabled or enabled.

Iwas wondering, is there any good approach to handle with this situation? Does anyone faced the same problem? How did you solved the problem?

Comment: you could show the `div` element there using `ng-bind` instead of showing disabled input..

Comment: Actually, we are trying to solve it in a more generic way, maybe marking the property with a readonly in my Angular controller. We use it a lot within the system. Our model came from a WebApi project, and the view is renderized by the MVC project in order to use some usefull features from Razor and .NET, such as localized resources, some validations and so on

Comment: You could do one thing use `ng-bind` when rendering disabled `input` element else render input with `ng-model`..you could use razor for this..

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I will only decide when the field is disabled when the Razor already did its job of rendering everything. Besides, sometimes deppending on the user action, I will set the disabled to true or false, it is not something that I can get before rendering or send the DOM to the client.

Comment: creating angular directive to render input element..we could pass `ng-model` and `isDisabled` attriubute and that will decide the input elelment will have `ng-bind`/`ng-model`